# Angular controllers expressed as ordinary Javascript functions

Tags: angularjs

I've been looking at a lot of Angular tutorials online, and I'm seeing some inconsistencies in the way that AngularJS controllers are defined.

Most examples use a ["chaining" syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19957280/angularjs-best-practices-for-module-declaration) when instantiating controllers:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []).controller('FooCtrl', function() {
    // $scope.foo = ...
});

// alternatively:

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller = function($scope, fooBar) {
    // $scope.foo = ...
}
```

In other examples I've seen, controllers are defined like you would define an [ordinary Javascript function](https://thinkster.io/egghead/ngfilter).  I think I've encountered this approach in more than one tutorial!

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function FooCtrl($scope, fooBar) {
    // $scope.foo = fooBar ...
});
```

- What's the difference between these two declarations?
- Is the second example simply *deprecated*?
- *If not*, then how does this Controller work with Angular's $digest cycle?

Comment: The second example is deprecated

Comment: @tymeJV I guess my assumption was correct, thanks.

Comment: 1st one is cool modularize approach..avoiding global function controller declaration

Comment: @tymeJV It looks like the second example was deprecated with the release of AngularJS 1.2.  Please post your comment as an answer and I will mark it as accepted!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the

```
function FooCtrl($scope, fooBar) {
    // $scope.foo = fooBar ...
});
```

function has been deprecated since the release of Angular 1.2.