# AngularJS boiler plate syntax

Tags: angularjs

One of the frustrations I face with AngularJS is the variety of styles that are used in examples. I have seen 4 different ways to declare and add AngularJS elements to a module (including different ways to declare the module). [In another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30239165/681009) I asked about using a global variable vs. directly declaring the module. Now I would like to know what are the advantages/disadvantages to using various styles to add elements to the module. (I will not include the examples that declare a global variable for the module, as that style has been discounted as a ['bad practice'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30239165/681009))

Assume the module is declared in file myMod.js as:

```
angular.module('myMod', [
        // Angular modules
        'ui.router'
        ,'ui.bootstrap'
        ,'ngResource'
        ,'ngStorage'

    ]);
```

Now I want to add a controller to the module, I have seen:

*(assume each example represents the entire contents of a file named: myController.js)*

option A:

```
angular.module('myMod')
        .controller.('thisController',['dependencyA','dependencyB',
        function(dependencyA, dependencyB){
....stuff to do
}]);
```

option B: just adding 'use strict'

```
'use strict';

 angular.module('myMod')
            .controller.('thisController',['dependencyA','dependencyB',
            function(dependencyA, dependencyB){
    ....stuff to do
    }]);
```

options C: wrapping the whole thing in an anonymous function as:

```
(function(){
'use strict';

angular.module('myMod')
            .controller.('thisController',['dependencyA','dependencyB',
            function(dependencyA, dependencyB){
    ....stuff to do
    }]);
```

option D: Declaring a named function rather than an anonymous function in the controller declaration as:

```
(function(){

'use strict'

angular
       .module('myMod')
       .controller('thisController',thisController);

thisController.$inject = ['dependencyA','dependencyB'];

function thisController(dependencyA,dependencyB){
...stuff to do
}
```

Similar diverse examples exist for adding factories, services, directives, etc. into a module. As best I can tell these are different styles for accomplishing the same goal. Which techniques represent 'best practices' and 'why'?

*(I am not wanting this to turn into an 'opinion piece' please offer 'objective' reasons to select a style.)*

Answer (score 2):

As for 'use strict', this has nothing to do with AngularjJS per se. It is a Javascript directive that enforces strict mode which prohibits the use of undeclared variables in Javascript. 
Immediately-Invoked Function Expression (IIFE) that wrap angular code prevent the leaking of variables into the global scope.
As for declaring a named function, in my opinion this leads to much clearer code and is my preferred way.

Answer (score 1):

They all perform the same job, I personally use the named function approach. But you can combine them if you want.

```
angular
       .module('myMod')
       .controller('thisController',['dependencyA', thisController]);

thisController.$inject = ['dependencyB'];

function thisController(dependencyA,dependencyB){
...stuff to do
}
```

I use TypeScript so my controllers look something like this.

```
export class thisController
{
        static $inject = ['DependencyA'];
        constructor(private _dependencyA: DependencyA)
        {

        }
}
 angular.module('myMod').controller('thisController', thisController)
```

Comment: I appreciate your thoughts, but I am really looking for a more objective analysis of 'best practices'...

Comment: As far as I know they only best practice is to make sure your dependencies are in quotes. This is so your code will still function if minified.