# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed) from Angularjs to WebApi

Tags: angularjs, json, post, asp.net-web-api

I am using AngularJS to call my webAPI and getting below error...

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed) http://localhost:52240/api/PcpEnvironment/
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:52240/api/PcpEnvironment/. Invalid HTTP status code 405
```

Here is my call to webapi...

```
    angular.module('PcPortal')

.controller('UpdateEnvironmentController', UpdateEnvironmentController);

UpdateEnvironmentController.$inject = ['$scope', '$http', '$rootScope'];

function UpdateEnvironmentController($scope, $rootScope, $http) {

    $scope.selectedEnv = $rootScope.selectedEnv;

    $scope.updateEnv = function () {
        alert('Updating env');
        var envData = angular.toJson($rootScope.selectedEnv);

        var config = {
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'http://localhost:52240/api/PcpEnvironment/Post/',
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            },
            data: { env: envData }
        };

        $http(config)
            .then(function successCallback(response) {
                alert(response);
            },
                function errorCallback(response) {
                    alert('Failed: ' + response);
                });

    }
};
```

WebApI method...

```
 [HttpPost]
        public bool Post(PcpEnvironment env)
        {
            return _service.UpdateEnvironment(env);
        }
```

in my webapiconfig file... I have added below,...

```
System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Clear();
            config.Formatters.Insert(0, new System.Net.Http.Formatting.JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
```

f I remove one `$http` ... my bindings stop working... and for `var webadmin = angular.module('PcPortal',[]);` I have separate bootstrap file to do that... here I am just getting the reference of same app.

In order to get my binding working... I need to change the order of input like below...

```
UpdateEnvironmentController.$inject = ['$scope', '$http', '$rootScope'];

function UpdateEnvironmentController($scope, $rootScope, $http)
```

With new definition of controller as suggeted... I am getting below error...

```
TypeError: object is not a function
```

This error is for using $http to make call to server.
Can help what's wrong here.

Comment: If everything is file on server side, Form status code 405 (Method not allowed), Possible reason could be you are not possible data correctly. In config can you try passing data as `envData` directly. instead of adding `env`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer of my question. sure after lot and lots of google.

By default POST, PUT methods are not allowed in webAPI. You either need to use CORS package for that or another solution is (I used to fix my issue)...

Add below config in web.config

```
<system.webServer>
     <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
```

and you also need to flush your OPTIONS request. Add below code in Global.aspx file...

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest()
        {
            if (Request.Headers.AllKeys.Contains("Origin") && Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
            {
                Response.Flush();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

remove one `$http` from the $inject

```
UpdateEnvironmentController.$inject = ['$scope', '$http', '$rootScope'];
```

Also, add an empty square bracket to the module

```
var webadmin = angular.module('PcPortal',[]);
```

Comment: if I remove one $http ... my bindings stop working... and for var webadmin = angular.module('PcPortal',[]); I have separate bootstrap file to do that... here I am just getting the reference of same app.

Comment: then remove the module from the js

Comment: Then How will I attach my controller with module. I have updated my question with more details. Pls have a look.

Comment: just use global variable to reference the module

Comment: I am very new to angularJS... can you point me to some example for the same

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30239165/why-is-setting-an-app-variable-a-bad-practice-in-angularjs

Comment: can you create a plnkr

Comment: I did created. since my app is dependent on webAPI... plnkr will not work...Here it is https://plnkr.co/edit/rCK8JJibm3ObBznr9MJx?p=preview

Comment: you missed to add the angular js library  and `ng-app` check this https://plnkr.co/edit/jGRI5Z1kf4JbIPWX1w4A?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for your help... I got the solution of my problem...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27504256/mvc-web-api-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use CORS package. 
Simply install package Owin.Cors at the Nuget package Console

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Owin.Cors
```

After this, you need to add the configuration at your startup.cs.
It will look something similar like below.

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();

            ConfigureOAuth(app);

            WebApiConfig.Register(config);
            app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
            app.UseWebApi(config);

        }
```