# AngularJS - the best way to write 'angular.module'?

Tags: angularjs

I have used

1. var app = angular.module('', []);
   app.controller...
2. angular.module('', []).controller()
3. (function() {
   var app = angular.module('', []);
   })();

and all of them work. But I don't understand the third one. What is this `(function() {})();`

and what's the best among the 3. Thanks.

Comment: This post may help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/19957452/5138917

Comment: Third one comes from ES6 convention, and hope it best to use.

Answer (score 4):

John Papa's Angular Style Guide explains why you should use #3 -  [Immediately Invoked Function Expressions](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#iife) :

> Why?: An IIFE removes variables from the global scope. This helps
>   prevent variables and function declarations from living longer than
>   expected in the global scope, which also helps avoid variable
>   collisions.
>
> Why?: When your code is minified and bundled into a single file for
>   deployment to a production server, you could have collisions of
>   variables and many global variables. An IIFE protects you against both
>   of these by providing variable scope for each file.

Answer (score 1):

its called self executing functions you could see it from here;

[What is the purpose of a self executing function in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/592396/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-self-executing-function-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

## 2 is correct

`angular.module('', []). controller() //<- correct`

`var app = angular.module('', []); app.controller` is not recommended since it creates a global variable, "app", which could confuse other scripts and is in any case unecessary.

`(function() { var app = angular.module('', []); })();` is better than #1 but it's unecessary, since the closure prevents the var `app` from being leaked, but it is not even being used in its closure.

Basically you only need the `function` closure if you're instantiating (and *using!*) variables.