# Simple dependancy injection in Angularjs not working

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    function myController($scope, $http) {
        var vm = this;
        $scope.text = "Delhi";
    }

    myController.$inject = ["$scope", "$http"];
    angular
       .module("app")
       .controller("myController", myController);
})();
```

And My Html Code is here

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="angular.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="myController">
        <p>I am from {{text}}</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

But I my project is not working as expected. Gives below error

https://www.dropbox.com/s/itd5ryar56zqcxn/Screenshot%202016-08-06%2023.46.04.png?dl=0

```
angular.js:68 Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'app' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.5/$injector/nomod?p0=app
```

Comment: Is `app` module declared in another file?

Comment: No, This is all. Please help this out.

Comment: So you have to declare your `app` like this: `angular.module("app", []);`

Comment: Can't it work without  `'[]'`

Comment: It only works if you already have it declared in another place/file (of course with the dependencies `[]`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few issues with the code,

(i) You need to define the module initially and then inject the controller

(ii) You forgot to add the empty dependencies to the module `'[]'`

```
(function () {
    "use strict"; 
    angular
       .module("app",[])
       .controller("myController", myController);
    function myController($scope, $http) {
        var vm = this;
        $scope.text = "Delhi";
    }
    myController.$inject = ["$scope", "$http"];    
}());
```

Here is the working **[`App`](https://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/pum3hvr7/10/)**

Comment: I know it works fine like this, But I also have seen many controller working without [] .
https://www.dropbox.com/s/bed9nwy5iacdvws/Screenshot%202016-08-07%2000.31.25.png?dl=0

Comment: @GopalSharma Yes its possible, but when you declare a module you need to define the dependencies, even with your example it should have been declared somewhere . Read more http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19957280/angularjs-best-practices-for-module-declaration