# Angular 1.6 Cant put more than one custom component in a page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using angular 1.6, and I have two components, config-list and request-dates.

The components work correctly if they are the only component on the page, but if I put more than one on a page, only the second one works. So in the page, below, request-dates works right.

Can there only be one component on a page?

Here's the main page:

```
<div ng-app="playground" ng-cloak>
    <config-list></config-list>
    <request-dates></request-dates>
</div>uest-

<script src="~/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/app/module.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/app/config-list.component.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/app/request-dates.component.js"></script>
```

Here's module.js:

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    angular.module("playground", []);    
}());
```

Here's config-list.component.js:

```
(function(){

    var module = angular.module("playground", []);

    function controller()
    {
        var model = this;
    };

    module.component("configList",
        {
            templateUrl: "/Scripts/app/config-list.component.html",
            controller: controller,
            controllerAs: "model"
        });
}());
```

Here's config-list.component.html:

```
<p>Hello from configlist</p>
```

Here's request-dates.component.js:

```
(function () {
    var module = angular.module("playground", []);

    function controller()
    {
        var model = this;
    }

    module.component("requestDates",
        {
            templateUrl: "/Scripts/app/request-dates.component.html",
            controller: controller,
            controllerAs: "model"
        });
}());
```

Here's request-dates.component.html:

```
<p>Hello from requestDates</p>
```

[Update] - as the correct answer showed, I was accidentally overwriting the module (which wiped out the first component) with a new module containing the second component, which explains why the first component was not appearing.

Comment: Try removing the brackets (and comma) from the module declaration in the external files

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS best practices for module declaration?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19957280/angularjs-best-practices-for-module-declaration)

Comment: No sh0ber, this is not a duplicate - a best practice link is not a duplicate answer, and as the answer below states I was accidentally redefining (and thereby overwriting) the existing module. Before you downvote someone's answer (which affects their reputation), you should be more careful.

Comment: This question is asked frequently (i.e. How do I use 2 modules / pages?)  Also, I did not leave that comment hoping for a reply.  It gets auto-generated by a close vote.

Comment: I didn't downvote anyone's answer though.

Comment: Im sorry then, my assumption was that marking things as a possible duplicate auto downvotes

Comment: I did downvote your question because I feel it's a duplicate but since it bothers you I will remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When accessing your `playground` module, you do not need the second parameter (dependencies).

So, in your `module.js` you have `var module = angular.module("playground", []);` which is the correct way to *create* a module.

Then in your `config-list.component.js` and `request-dates.component.js`, you should be just *accessing* your module, NOT *creating* them.

Accessing an already created module:
`var module = angular.module("playground");`